# How to combine a list model to another model in ASP.NET MVC3

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, model

I have two models:

```
public class Model1
    {
        public int? Id { get; set; }    
        public string Name{ get; set; }
        private IList<Model2> _model2; 
    } 

  public class Model2
        {
           public string Name2{ get; set; }
        }
```

JSON data for ajax call:

```
[
  {
    "Id": 1,
    "Name": "Foo",
    "Name2": "Foo2"
  },
  {
    "Id": 2,
    "Name": "Foo3",
    "Name2": "Foo4"
  }
]
```

Controller action:

```
public ActionResult Save(List<Model1> models)
        {
        }
```

In this way I do not get `Name2` in controller action. Are there any way to get `Name2` in controller?

I know it can be solved by creating another model. e.g

```
public class Model3
        {
            public int? Id { get; set; }    
            public string Name{ get; set; }
            private Model2 _model2; 
        }
```

But I don't want to create new model class. 
thanks....

Comment: `"_model2": [{ "Name2": "Foo2" }]`

Comment: I am reading data from excel using a JS plugin, it returns data in that format.....Should I convert data to your suggested format in client side?

Comment: I suggest it would be easier to just create a view model as your indicated (your `Model3`) and then map it back to `Model1` in the controller.

Answer (score 1):

JSON data should be in this format

```
[
  {
    "Id": 1,
    "Name": "Foo",
    "_model2":[{"Name2": "Foo2"}]
  },
  {
    "Id": 2,
    "Name": "Foo3",
     "_model2":[{"Name2": "Foo4"}]
  }
]
```

Comment: Can you please provide a way to convert my JSON data to your suggested format?

Comment: how you create this json data?

Answer (score 1):

You can derive Model1 from Model2 like this;

```
public class Model1:Model2
{
    public int? Id { get; set; }    
    public string Name{ get; set; }        
}
```

Now you should see Name2 as a property in Model1 and your Json should work as it is.

Comment: I cannot see a base class in your code; even if you have it, you will be able to do this;  public class Model1: MyBaseClass, Model2

Comment: Yes u r right, base class is not mentioned here. If I add `Model1: MyBaseClass, Model2`, I face the error `Model1 cannot have multiple base class`

Comment: You can do the above only if you're deriving from an interface already.

Comment: @KosalaW what you are trying to prove?